# A SortedList.IndexOfKey(key) that returns the index of the item where item.key >= key

Tags: .net, sortedlist

*SortedList<TKey, TValue>.IndexOfKey(key)* returns -1 if *key* is not in the list.

Does this mean I have to implement a binary search myself if I want to find the index of the key in the list that is greater or equal to *key*? Or is there something out of the box that I overlooked?

I want to get the result in O(log(n)) of course, so please no LINQ iterate and filter magic.

(In general, I'd like to have something like Java's NavigableMap functionality, i.e. features like efficient iteration over a sorted map/dictionary, but for now, an answer to the above question would suffice, I can "extension-method" my way from there somehow)

Comment: its very strange that List has binary search, but SortedList doesn't have binary search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're out of luck, there's nothing built-in.

If you create a binary search extension method for `IList<T>` then you could use it against the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132379.aspx) property. This is a bit annoying, though not too difficult.

(The convention used by the framework's built-in binary search methods -- [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fxw5t8z.aspx) and [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx) -- is to return the bitwise complement of the index of the next element when the element isn't found.)

```
int index = yourSortedList.Keys.YourBinarySearchExtensionMethod(key);
if (index >= 0)
{
    // key found
}
else
{
    // key not found
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the builtin List<T>.BinarySearch method. With that, all that remains is a bit of plumbing. (Not that implementing binary search would require anything like a PhD)

Answer (score 3):

So here it is, for posterity, including myself, as I'm yet again in need of a `NavigableMap` in .net. `BinarySearch` extension methods that work for `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` and overloads that work for any `IList<T>`.

```
public static class BinarySearch4All
{
    public static int BinarySearch<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> sortedList,
            TKey value, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        return BinarySearch(sortedList, 0, sortedList.Count, value, comparer);
    }

    public static int BinarySearch<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> sortedList,
            int index, int length, TKey value, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        return BinarySearch(sortedList.Keys, index, length, value, comparer);
    }

    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> list, T value, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        return BinarySearch(list, 0, list.Count, value, comparer);
    }

    // algorithm courtesy of http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/arraysorthelper.cs#114ea99d8baee1be
    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> list, int index, int length,
            T value, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (comparer == null)
            comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        int lo = index;
        int hi = index + length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi)
        {
            int i = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            int order = comparer.Compare(list[i], value);

            if (order == 0) return i;
            if (order < 0)
                lo = i + 1;
            else
                hi = i - 1;
        }
        return ~lo;
    }
}
```

N.B. I wonder why there is no `IRandomAccess<T>` in .net, which at least `IList<T>` and arrays would derive from.

`SortedList<TKey, TValue>` could actually derive from `IRandomAccess<TKey>`, as well as `IRandomAccess<TValue>` and `IRandomAccess<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.