# C# ordered dictionary object that supports finding closest key?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, data-structures, ordereddictionary

Is there any ordered dictionary collection available in C# that provides a ready means of finding the first key greater than a value if the sought value isn't present?

I.e., `if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(some_key))` then return the next `key > some_key` based on the dictionary's ordering predicate?

If there's a clever way of doing this with delegates an example of that would be equally appreciated!

Comment: Try `SortedDictionary`.                                                     `SortedDictionary<string, string> openWith = 
    new SortedDictionary<string, string>()`

Comment: I think there is no implementation for it. As @Vadim said, in .Net has SortedDictionary and you can try it out. With Linq, we have `OrderBy()` method, which allows us to order the data, but just order.

Comment: Your best option is probably to use a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` and do a binary search on the keys. `SortedList` has an `IndexOfKey` method but it doesn't allow you to find where the key would be in the case of a failed search. Unfortunately there's also no built-in binary search method for `IList<Key>` either so you'd have to do that manually.

Comment: I meant that one can create a list out of SortedDictionary key or values and iterate trough using their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a great binary-search implementation for any sorted `IList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120555/2662901): If the exact key doesn't exist, it returns the `~index` of the next greatest key.

With that class in scope one can just do something like the following:

```
SortedList myList;
int nextBiggestKey; // Index of key >= soughtValue
if((nextBiggestKey = myList.Keys.BinarySearch(soughtValue)) < 0)
{
   if(~nextBiggestKey > myList.Count) continue; // soughtValue is larger than largest key in myList
   nextBiggestKey = ~nextBiggestKey
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Vadim suggested, your best bet would be the [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation which stores the keys sorted. From there you could do the following:

```
var next = dictionary.ContainsKey(key)
                ? dictionary[key]
                : dictionary.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key > key).Value;
```

The dictionary.FirstOrDefault will return the first key value pair where the key is greater than the desired key. If there are none, then a blank key-value pair is returned {,} and the value returned should be the default value of the type stored. Since I was playing with a SortedDictionary, it returned null.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string> {{1, "First"}, {2, "Second"}, {10, "10th"}};
            Console.WriteLine(GetNext(1, dictionary));
            Console.WriteLine(GetNext(3, dictionary));
            Console.WriteLine(GetNext(11, dictionary));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GetNext(int key, SortedDictionary<int, string> dictionary)
        {
            return dictionary.ContainsKey(key)
                ? dictionary[key]
                : dictionary.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key > key).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does a linear search through the keys when `O(lg N)` should be possible.

Comment: It definitely could be improved if performance is a concern, particularly b/c the the keys are sorted. This was just prototyped to show how it could be done.